# Solving for three parameters from a matrix equation and storing them in separate variables

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

Say I have a matrix

$$
Z=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{i}{\sqrt 2} \\ \frac{i}{\sqrt 2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \end{pmatrix}
$$

and another matrix

$$
U(\theta, \phi, \lambda) = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & -e^{i\lambda} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \\
e^{i\phi} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) & e^{i(\lambda + \phi)} \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I now want to solve for $\theta$, $\phi$ and $\lambda$ such that $Z=U$ ($0 \leq \phi <2\pi$, $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $0\leq \lambda < 2\pi$). Is there any way to do this directly using say [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)? From the documentation, it seems that it works only for single equations rather than matrix equations like these. Is there any workaround so that I can directly solve for the three parameters and store them in three different variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
Z={{-1/Sqrt[2],I/Sqrt[2]},{I/Sqrt[2],-1/Sqrt[2]}};
U={{Cos[θ/2],-E^(I λ)Sin[θ/2]}, {E^(I φ)Sin[θ/2],E^(I(λ+φ))Cos[θ/2]}};
Reduce[Z==U,{θ,φ,λ}]
```

shows you the conditions for the multiple different solutions for your example problem.

In this particular example problem `FullSimplify` is able to eliminate all the inverse trig functions and radicals in the solution.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please check [this issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199121/why-is-this-mathematica-code-unable-to-solve-for-the-real-parameter-set)?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified [Bill's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199113/63834) a bit to include the domain restriction and return approximate numerical values rather than exact values using trigonometric functions like `arcsin`, `arctan`, `arccos`, etc.

```
Z = {{-1/Sqrt[2], I/Sqrt[2]}, {I/Sqrt[2], -1/Sqrt[2]}};
U = {{Cos[\[Theta]/
      2], -E^(I \[Lambda]) Sin[\[Theta]/
       2]}, {E^(I \[CurlyPhi]) Sin[\[Theta]/2], 
    E^(I (\[Lambda] + \[CurlyPhi])) Cos[\[Theta]/2]}};
N[Reduce[Z == U && 0 <= \[CurlyPhi] < 2 Pi && 0 <= \[Theta] < Pi &&  
   0 <= \[Lambda] < 2 Pi, {\[Theta], \[CurlyPhi], \[Lambda]}]]
```

This produces:

```
\[Theta] == 4.71239 && \[CurlyPhi] == 1.5708 + 0. I && \[Lambda] == 4.71239 + 0. I
```

Comment: I ran your code, but I couldn't get your result. The result is False. (MMA v13.0)